# How to block a user in apache httpd server from accessing a *.php file inside a Directory, instead user should access this using Directory name

Tags: php, apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-server

My requirement looks Simple, But Googling Did not help me yet.
    my query is
    i want to Throw a 404 page to a user(Not Re-Direct to another folder or file), 
    who is trying to Access *.php files in my website

ex:  when a client asks for 
   **www.example.com/home/** i want to show the content ,
   but when user says

**www.example.com/home/index.php**  i want to show a 404 page.

i tried different methods, nothing worked for me, 
   one of which tried is shown below

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/*">
    <FilesMatch "^\.php">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        ErrorDocument 403 /test/404/
        ErrorDocument 404 /test/404/
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my .htaccess file. you can demo it out here:
http://mathpdq.com/demo2    or
http://mathpdq.com/demo2/index.php

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /demo2
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mathpdq\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mathpdq.com/demo2/$1 [R=permanent,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This solution is working when i request the folder,  but when i request folder/index.php  instead of showing my 404 page   it shows Not found error "The requested URL /test/index.php was not found on this server." also it shows  "Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: @Oxi I modified my answer. in addition to what I think you are looking for it forces the url to have www at the beginning

Comment: i am not using .htaccess,  i added you code snippet  with small modification into my Directory  as shown below
    `RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /test

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/test/$1 [R=permanent,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`
This gives me an infinite loop

Comment: http://www.lancelhoff.com/enabling-htaccess-in-apache-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Just a basic rewrite rule, you can place this as .htaccess file in your folder or in your server config or virtual host config

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

//allowed files, just remove the ! to use this rule to deny
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css|js|jpg|gif|png|zip|tff)

//redirect location
RewriteRule (.*) /public/www/404.php
```

Comment: This makes my server Just opposite to what is intended :) .. When i request with folder name it throws "Internal Server Error"  and when i request folder/index.php  it works fine